# brew uninstall package deletes usr/local folder

Tags: macos, homebrew, uninstallation

I tried to uninstall mysql from my Mac via brew
`brew uninstall mysql`

however this command removed whole usr/local folder

I checked trash but unable to locate this.

Is there a way to get it back?